# script to remove lines that have same string at the end of the line and save the remaining lines in another file in another format

Tags: python

my file looks like that:

```
|#tail |head   |edge_weight|edge_type                                   |
|Q8TBF5|Q9UKB1 |3.11133e-01|MI:0004 (affinity chromatography technology)|
|Q8TBF4|QQ15696|2.01461e-01|MI:0401 (biochemical)                       |
|Q8TBF4|Q15696 |3.11133e-01|MI:0004 (affinity chromatography technology)|
```

I want to remove lines that have 'MI:0004 (affinity chromatography technology)' and save the other line in another file also I want to change the format to be some thing like that:

```
|#Tail|head    |edge_weight|edge_type            |
|Q8TBF4|QQ15696|0.201461   |MI:0401 (biochemical)|
```

note that changed the original edge_weight to float but i get error when i run my script.

My script:

```
from math import log
file_path_in_2 = 'D:/Courses/Bioinformatics Diploma/Programming to bioinformatics/Assignments/Assignment_03/PathLinker_PPI.txt'
file_in_2 = open(file_path_in_2, 'r')
file_path_out_2 = 'D:/Courses/Bioinformatics Diploma/Programming to bioinformatics/Assignments/Assignment_03/PathLinker_PPI_others.txt'
file_out_2 = open(file_path_out_2, 'w')

file_out_2.write('#tail|head\tedge_weight\tedge_type\n')
for line in file_in_2:
     if 'MI:0004 (affinity chromatography technology)' not in line:
         line_items = line.split('\t')
         edge_weight = float(line_items[2])
         edge_weight = 1 - (edge_weight)
         new_string = '%s|%s\t%f\t%s' %(line_items[0], line_items[1], edge_weight, line_items[3])
         file_out_2.write(new_string)
file_out_2.close()
file_in_2.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\CIT656\pythonProjects\CIT656_Spring21\Assignment_03.py", line 29, in <module>
    edge_weight = float(line_items[2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'edge_weight'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try to figure out why the statement on line 29 might be trying to convert the string `'edge_weight'` to a float. Is it trying to parse the heading text maybe?

Comment: yes by using '\t'

Comment: Consider changing the question title to something like 'ValueError when parsing tab delimited text from file' because this is what the problem relates to specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but try adding the following statement after `line_items = line.split('\t')`

```
if line_items[0] == '#tail':
    continue
```

This will cause it to skip the heading row in the data file.

Or you could add this immediately after opening the file:

```
file_in_2.readline()
```

This will read in and ignore the first line in the file.

Comment: No problem.  The information to solve the problem was in the Traceback message.  Always read the Traceback carefully and think about why it occurred.  Usually this leads to understanding the problem and how to fix it.